# Composer 2 and CiviCRM Installation Error

Tags: drupal, composer

I am trying to install CiviCRM on a Drupal 8 site using Composer 2.  I am getting the error below.  Is this a Composer 2 issue?  Do I need to revert to Composer 1?  Is there a different fix?  Thx.

=======================================

composer require civicrm/civicrm-{core,packages,drupal-8}:'~5.36'

./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update civicrm/civicrm-core civicrm/civicrm-packages civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- civicrm/civicrm-core[5.36.0, ..., 5.37.x-dev] require symfony/finder ~3.0 || ~4.4 -> found symfony/finder[v3.0.0-BETA1, ..., 3.4.x-dev, v4.4.0-BETA1, ..., 4.4.x-dev] but the package is fixed to v5.2.4 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
- Root composer.json requires civicrm/civicrm-core ~5.36 -> satisfiable by civicrm/civicrm-core[5.36.0, 5.36.1, 5.36.x-dev, 5.37.x-dev].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

Comment: Based on the error message, I would try removing composer.lock and the entire vendor folder and also web/modules/contrib/civicrm then trying again. It sounds like an earlier attempt failed and it's now in a stuck situation. Composer 2 should work, but also is this drupal 8 or 9?

Comment: @Demerit, Thank you very much.  Your suggestions worked.  This is on a Drupal 8 site that I used a theme demo as the starter.  That might have created a bit of a goofy setup to begin with.  Thanks again!

Comment: Great, glad it worked.

Comment: Just to keep the record going (and for anyone who has a similar issues), this also happened on a Drupal 9 vanilla installation.  The solution also works on D9.  Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments there were some leftover installed vendor files and removing composer.lock and the entire vendor folder and also web/modules/contrib/civicrm and then trying again clears it.